# Phpmyadmin with SSL on a single subdomain

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I would like to access phpmyadmin on a unique subdomain. I've created a virtualhost, everything works fine but I use many subdomains and they all give me access to phpmyadmin.

I want that only one subdomain points to phpmyadmin.

`https://static01.domain.com`  => point to phpmyadmin (and shouldn't)

`https://pma.domain.com`  => point to phpmyadmin  (OK, but I would like only this one)

Here is my virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName static01.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/O2/..
</VirtualHost>
..
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName pma.domain.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

   SSLEngine On
   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.key
   SSLProxyEngine  on
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Remove the Alias declaration of PHPMyAdmin from your apache2 configuration document. `Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Comment: thank you for your answer but there is no alias in apache2.conf, even when I remove include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf, still the same.. any idea ?

Comment: try to change `<VirtualHost *:443>` to `<VirtualHost pma.domain.com:443>` and restart your server

Answer (score 0):

In apache2.conf you will find a line at the bottom:

`Include conf.d/`

What this does is include ALL files in the `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` directory.

So have a look in this folder and you will likely find a file named `phpmyadmin.conf`. You can simply delete it.

Comment: thanks but there is no cond.d directory in /etc/apache2/, I use ubuntu 14

Comment: OK well look for something at the bottom of apache2.conf that's similar (e.g. just `Include somefolder/`) and delete it from there instead

Comment: I've put in comment include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf but nothing has changed, grr, that makes me crazy, any idea ?

Comment: That's not what I said to do. Try this: `find /etc/apache2/ -name phpmyadmin.conf` - this will show you the location of the file you need to delete. Don't forget to reload Apache afterwards.

Comment: this cmd return nothing. In /etc/apache2/ there is only ports.conf and apache2.conf (and other directories like site-available)

Comment: How did you add phpMyAdmin? Through an installer e.g. apt-get?

Comment: It usually resides in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf but @julien said he commented that out and it didn't work :s

Comment: That really depends how it was installed. With aptitude on my distro, it will create the file I mentioned above. On others it will create an alias. Personally I'd just uninstall it and upload the files manually xD Or usually... `svn co https://phpmyadmin.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/phpmyadmin/tags/STABLE/phpMyAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the right direction, but I think you should add some extra security directives.

Below my current configuration, based on the original `phpMyAdmin.conf` that was created after the `yum` package installation in CentOS 7. For other systems paths could be different, or if you use a different Apache/PHP version, some commands can also change, but you should be able to find the replacement.

I'm commenting the original directives, and also some other directives that might be useful:

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

#Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
#Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #  # Apache 2.4
   #  <RequireAny>
   #    Require ip 127.0.0.1
   #    Require ip ::1
   #  </RequireAny>
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #  # Apache 2.2
   #  Order Deny,Allow
   #  Deny from All
   #  Allow from 127.0.0.1
   #  Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
#        SecRuleInheritance Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>

<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XX.XX:443>
  ServerName your.domain.com

  DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
        DirectoryIndex index.php
      Require all granted

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
    php_value include_path .
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpMyAdmin/tmp
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpMyAdmin:/etc/phpMyAdmin:/var/lib/phpMyAdmin:/usr/share/php/gettext:doc/html
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
  </Directory>

  #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  #LogLevel warn

  #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your/certificate.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your/key.key
  #SSLVerifyClient none
  #SSLOptions +StrictRequire
  SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
  SSLProxyEngine off
  #<IfModule mime.c>
  # AddType application/x-509-ca-cert .crt
  # AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl .crl
  #</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

This should give you a much more secure installation open to the public. If anyone has further suggestions I'm happy to hear.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, for those interested this thing did the trick :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>  (need to be 1st, for any subdomains)
    ServerName domain.com
    RedirectPermanent / "http://www.domain.com:80"

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.key
    SSLProxyEngine on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName pma.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/server.key
    SSLProxyEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```